# destroyed activity on call fragment

Tags: android-studio

I import 
`androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`,
`androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`,
`androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager`

and I used following transactions to beginning a fragment into a `FrameLayout` on Main Activity

```
    FragmentManager fm = new AppCompatActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmen_container);

    if(fragment==null){
        fragment= new CrimeFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmen_container,fragment).commit();
    }
```

but my activity destroyed.

Stack Trace/Logcat :

```
2020-06-04 13:30:41.819 31140-31140/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.criminalintent, PID: 31140
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.criminalintent/com.example.criminalintent.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3303)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:2114)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:683)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:637)
    at com.example.criminalintent.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

2020-06-04 13:30:41.859 31140-31140/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31140 SIG: 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I think your problem is here

```
FragmentManager fm = new AppCompatActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

try this

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

regards.

Comment: hi brother , i try to set this but android studio unknown getsupportFragmentMaanager alone

Comment: Hello, it works for me, you can see how I use it in a project. (https://github.com/CarlesRa/PM_ExerciciCartes/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/carlesramos/pm_exercicicartes/activities/MainActivity.java)

you can try  (fm = MainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager ();) Regards.